# Format Ruby string to 3 characters with an integer

Tags: ruby

I'd like for this script

```
 (1..134).each do |x|
   puts "0#{x}" # ????
 end
```

to output:

```
001
002
...
011
...
134
```

Is this possible without doing a bunch of if statements using just native format? It doesn't need to handle greater than 3 digits.

Comment: FYI, Ruby can also iterate numerical strings: `('001'..'134').each { |s| puts s }`

Comment: What @Stefan said although I prefer the readability and ephemeral nature of `#upto`  e.g. `'001'.upto('134')`

Comment: What @Stefan said, modified `puts [*'001'..'134']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. It can be done using the following formatter:

```
'%03d' % 1   # 001
'%03d' % 10  # 010
'%03d' % 100 # 100
```

The loop is going to look like this:

```
(1..134).each { |x| puts '%03d' % x }
```

There's also [Kernel#format](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) method, which does exactly this, but self-explanatory:

```
(1..134).each { |x| puts format('%03d', x) }
```

Comment: This *works* but it's going to be completely mystifying to a novice who wants to know *how* it works.

Comment: Alternatively: `1.upto(134) { |i| printf("%03d\n", i) }`

Comment: @JordanRunning where is @mudasobwa to pull out a `(1..134).each(&method(:printf).curry(2).call("%03d\n"))`

Comment: The documentation for the `%` operator is here: [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-25). The format string is specified in [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), of which `Kernel#format` is an alias.

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve the zero padding you want is to use [`#rjust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-rjust):

```
(1..134).each do |x|
  puts x.to_s.rjust(3, '0')
end
```

Hope this helps!